# Get actual JFrame size in swing after packing it

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, dimensions

I've created `JFrame` and set its size to `800x600`:

```
frame.setSize(800, 600);
```

Then I've created `JPanel` and inserted it in my `JFrame`:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

But it's actual dimensions are less then `JFrame` dimensions, because of title bar and frame border heights, which vary in different operating systems.

---

Then I've tried one more approach.

I've created frame without setting its size.

And after that I've created `JPanel` and set its preferred size:

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
```

Then I've packed my `Jframe` with:

```
frame.pack();
```

---

How can I determine actual `JFrame` size now?

Comment: don't call setXXSize, ever:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JFrame` size can be determined by:

```
frame.getSize()
```

And `Jframe` content pane size (excluding title bar and system window borders) can be determined by:

```
frame.getContentPane().getSize()
```